# Insert data into Oracle table Using Python script. Expected str instance, bytes found

Tags: python, oracle, byte, sql-insert, cx-oracle

I want to insert data into Oracle Table, where one row type-RAW(In python BYTES).

```
sql = f"INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO {table}  ({columns}) VALUES  ({values})"
ins_r = ', '.join(lst)
cur.execute(sql, ins_r)
```

This is my printed SQL:

```
INFO - INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO TR.ZZ_TEST  (REGION_ID, REGION_NAME, CHANGE_DATE, MD5) VALUES  (:REGION_ID, :REGION_NAME, :CHANGE_DATE, :MD5)
```

And this my data which I want to Insert:

```
['1', "'TEST'", "to_date('2021-09-28 18:48:23','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')", b'aWQ\x9b\xa6(\x17zj\xab\x97\x8e\x12uE4']
```

And I have the error:

```
ins_r = ', '.join(lst)
TypeError: sequence item 3: expected str instance, bytes found
```

And I wanted to convert bytes to str, but is not correct.

Comment: The second argument to `cur.execute()` should be a list of all the values, not a string.

Comment: And if you're using named parameters, it should be a dictionary.

Comment: And datatypes should be corresponding python datatypes. There cannot be `to_date` or anything similar, because bind variables substitute the data, and the data is passed as is, not as SQL expression (because it is not a part of SQL statement and is not evaluated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your parameter to list of tuples in order to be able insert multiple values along with using `executemany` method rather than `execute` as being more performant for bulk loads.

Convert the current `to_date` conversion of the DB to `datetime.datetime`(a type of `datetime` module), and count the number commas within the `columns` string in order to generate a bind variables list(`values` -> in this case `:0, :1, :2, :3`)

```py
import cx_Oracle
import datetime
...
...
table = 'tr.zz_test'
columns = 'region_id,region_name,change_date,md5'
prm=[    
    (11,'TEST1',datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 29, 17, 28, 11),b'aWQ\x9b\xa6(\x17zj\xab\x97\x8e\x12uE4'),
    (12,'TEST2',datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 28, 18, 48, 23),b'aWQ\x9b\xa5(\x17zj\xab\x97\x8e\x12uE2')
]

val=""
for i in range(0,columns.count(",")+1):
    val+=':'.join(' '+str(i)) + ','
values=val.rstrip(",")
my_query = f"INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO {table}({columns}) VALUES({values})"

cur.executemany(my_query,prm)
con.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `cur.execute()` should be the list of values, not a string made by joining them. So use

```
cur.execute(sql, lst)
```